# left alignment the output of a powershell command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am running the following command, and I would like to align the output to the left...just can't figure it out:

Basically, this is providing me the size of a specific directory and it is right aligned.

`Get-ChildItem c:\users\xxx\desktop -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum|Select-object @{Name="Total size GB "; Expression={$_.Sum / 1GB}}  >> c:\users\xxx\desktop\pwr\bkp.txt`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace your Select-Object with Format-Table like this:

```
Format-Table -Property @{ Name="Size in GB"; Expression={$_.Sum / 1GB }; Alignment="left"; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Quick & dirty - format it as a table, auto-sized:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\users\xxx\desktop -recurse |
    Measure-Object -property length -sum|
    format-table -autosize @{Name="Total size GB "; Expression={$_.Sum / 1GB}} >> c:\users\xxx\desktop\pwr\bkp.txt
```

But I prefer to use `out-file` instead of redirection:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\users\xxx\desktop -recurse |
    Measure-Object -property length -sum|
    format-table @{Name="Total size GB "; Expression={$_.Sum / 1GB}} -autosize |
    | out-file -append -path c:\users\xxx\desktop\pwr\bkp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

took me some time today...after posting the question, found an answer that does the job for me..
i have replaced select-object with ft and this aligns it to left, as expected.

before:

Get-ChildItem c:\users\xxx\desktop -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum|Select-object @{Name="Total size GB "; Expression={$_.Sum / 1GB}} >> c:\users\xxx\desktop\pwr\bkp.txt

after:
Get-ChildItem c:\users\xxx\desktop -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum|ft @{Name="Total size GB "; Expression={$_.Sum / 1GB};align=left} >>   c:\users\xxx\desktop\pwr\bkp.txt

Answer (score 0):

format-table is very special command.Once you use format-table command you should not use any other command. If any of the objects of output of select is blank then your output file will not show that . Format table is the last thing that you do in your script. You will get , ,, , , ,

Put get-member in the end and see what are you goin to get - is it property or object. It will be about format data but not actual data.

Instead use out-file or out-host with format-table